# Selector question

Tags: jquery, selector

I want to get a list of objects which doesn't have some style name in attributes.

```
<div style="yes"></div>
<div style="no"></div>

$("div !no").(/* ... */) { }
```

Something like that: check all divs which doesn't have 'no' class in style attribute.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you using invalid style attributes here?

Comment: Can you make a real world example? I assume it's not going to be `yes` or `no ` literally right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, that'd be `$("div :not(.no)");`

Also, that should be `class="yes"` and `class="no"`

Comment: As an optimization, `$("div :not(div.no)")` may be faster; I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the not equal to selector - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[class!=no]')....
```

That what you're looking for? I suggest taking a look at the selectors page, this will give you all the ways you can find (or exclude) something. ( http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ )

Comment: You should fix to `$('div[class!="no"]')` (read on http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/: "Quotes are mandatory").

Answer (score 0):

If you're really looking for entries not containing "no" in the style attribute, this should work:

```
$('div:not([style="no"])')
```

Though I think this won't work at all as the browser remove invalid style attributes when rendering the page.